# Write BNFC grammar for a C++ program

Tags: c++, parsing, bnfc

So I am writing a grammar using the [BNF-Convertor (BNFC)](http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/) to parse a c++ program. The c++ program is as follows.

```
// a small C++ program
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "i";
    return 0;
}
```

The BNF grammar I wrote for this is as follows.

```
PDefs. Program ::= [Def] ;
terminator Def "" ;
comment "//" ;
comment "/*" "*/" ;
comment "#" ;
DFun. Def ::= Type Id "(" [Arg] ")" "{" [Stm] "}" ;
separator Arg "," ;
terminator Stm "" ;
separator nonempty Id "::" ;
ADecl. Arg ::= Type Id ;
SExp.    Stm ::= Exp ";"              ;
Sids.    Stm ::= Id                   ;
SDecl.   Stm ::= Type Id ";"          ;
SDecls.  Stm ::= Type Id "," [Id] ";" ;
SInit.   Stm ::= Type Id "=" Exp ";"  ;
SReturn. Stm ::= "return" Exp ";"     ;
SWhile.  Stm ::= "while" "(" Exp ")" Stm ;
SBlock.  Stm ::= "{" [Stm] "}" ;
SIfElse. Stm ::= "if" "(" Exp ")" Stm "else" Stm ;
EInt.    Exp15 ::= Integer ;
EDouble. Exp15 ::= Double ;
ETrue.   Exp15 ::= "true" ;
EFalse.  Exp15 ::= "false" ;
EId.     Exp15 ::= Id ;
EApp.    Exp15 ::= Id "(" [Exp] ")" ;
EStr.    Exp15 ::= "\"" Id "\"";
EPIncr.  Exp14 ::= Exp15 "++" ;
EPDecr.  Exp14 ::= Exp15 "--" ;
EIncr.   Exp13 ::= "++" Exp14 ;
EDecr.   Exp13 ::= "--" Exp14 ;
ETimes.  Exp12 ::= Exp12 "*" Exp13 ;
EDiv.    Exp12 ::= Exp12 "/" Exp13 ;
EPlus.   Exp11 ::= Exp11 "+" Exp12 ;
EMinus.  Exp11 ::= Exp11 "-" Exp12 ;
ELs.     Exp9  ::= Exp9 "<<" Exp10 ;
ERs.     Exp9  ::= Exp9 ">>" Exp10 ;
ELt.     Exp9  ::= Exp9 "<"  Exp10 ;
EGt.     Exp9  ::= Exp9 ">" Exp10 ;
ELtEq.   Exp9  ::= Exp9 "<=" Exp10 ;
EGtWq.   Exp9  ::= Exp9 ">=" Exp10 ;
EEq.     Exp8  ::= Exp8 "==" Exp9 ;
ENEq.    Exp8  ::= Exp8 "!=" Exp9 ;
EAnd.    Exp4  ::= Exp4 "&&" Exp5 ;
EOr.     Exp3  ::= Exp3 "||" Exp4 ;
EAss.    Exp2  ::= Exp3 "=" Exp2 ;
coercions Exp 15 ; 
separator Exp "," ;
separator Id "," ;
Tbool. Type ::= "bool" ;
Tdouble. Type ::= "double" ;
Tint. Type ::= "int" ;
Tvoid. Type ::= "void" ;
token Id (letter (letter | digit | '_' )*) ;
token Ids (letter)* ;
```

I have written the rules for both `::` and the left shift operators here `<<` and `>>` right shift operators but for some reason it's not parsing correctly. What am I doing wrong?

According to my understanding this should work but it gives this error.

> ```
>    syntax error at line 6 before << "i" ; return
> ```

Comment: That's not BNF.

Comment: Googled "C++ bnf" and found [Hyperlinked C++ BNF Grammar](http://nongnu.org/hcb/). On the first glance, it looks impressive. From my experiments with C, I remember that the C language is not context free. (E.g. I needed some tricks to distinguish parenthesized expressions from cast operators.) From what I heard, it's even more worse in C++.

Comment: @rici Any idea how i would go about that?

Comment: @zeist: Go about what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `std::cout` is not an `Id`. It might be an `[Id]` -- that is, a list of `Id`s -- because of the declaration

```
separator nonempty Id "::" ;
```

but that declaration conflicts with the later declaration

```
separator Id "," ;
```

I don't know enough about BNFC to predict the result of that conflict, but it is hard to imagine that the result is what you want.

The syntax for an expression does not use `[Id]`; it only allows `Id`:

```
EId.     Exp15 ::= Id ;
EApp.    Exp15 ::= Id "(" [Exp] ")" ;
```

So the qualified name `std::cout` is not going to be parsed as an `Exp15`.

You have two very different contexts in which you attempt to use lists of `Id`s; they differ both syntactically and semantically. So you really cannot expect to use `[Id]` for both of them.

Since you evidently want to be able to handle namespace'd names, I'd suggest explicitly defining `Name` as a non-empty `::`-separated list of `Id`s. You could use the `[Id]` macro instead of your own definition, of course; that's really a judgement of style. To me, it seems less clear but tastes vary.

In the other context -- declarations -- the use of `[Id]` is really not correct, although it might be sufficient for your simplified grammar. Here, I'd recommend using a new `Declarator` non-terminal, which you could initially define as just `Id` but which you will eventually want to expand to include pointer declarators (`*foo`), array declarators (`foo[3]`) and maybe even function declarators. With the `Declarator` non-terminal, you can replace

```
SDecl.   Stm ::= Type Id ";"          ;
SDecls.  Stm ::= Type Id "," [Id] ";" ;
```

with

```
separator nonempty Declarator ","
SDecls.  Stm ::= Type [Declarator] ";" ;
```

---

Note: from the "LBNF Grammar Formalism", in section 7 (Macros):

> ```
> separator nonempty Stm ";" ;
> ```
>
> means
>
> ```
> (:[]). [Stm] ::= Stm ;
> (:). [Stm] ::= Stm ";" [Stm] ;
> ```

Comment: I have added this :
separator nonempty Ident "::" ;
Sname.   Ids ::= [Ident];
Eids.    Exp9  ::= Ids;
ELs.     Exp9  ::= Exp9 "<<" Exp11 ;
ERs.     Exp9  ::= Exp9 ">>" Exp11 ;
Its still not parsing correctly

Comment: @zeist: the code in your comment is (a) unreadable and (b) very different from yor question. (What is `Ident`, for example? What happened to precedence levels 10 through 15? Etc.) And "still not parsing correctly" is ambiguous. Do you get the same error at the same place? Or do you get a different error? Usually the best thing to do is to ask a new question with correct details.

Comment: I get the same error at the same line. So i have added a new identifier named Ident and the precedence levels from 10 to 15 are still there..

Comment: @Zeist Adding a new token type (`Ident`) won't work and is not what I suggested. I suggested adding a new non-terminal to represent a *list* of `Id`s, without using the macro form `[Id]`. (Or using the macro form if you want, as long as you remove the other use of `[Id]` with comma separators.

Comment: Sname.   Ids ::= Id "::" Ids;
Like this right?

Comment: @zeist: See the definition of [] in the manual (but I think that I'd write it as `Ids ::= Ids :: Id`) and you need a base case (`Ids ::= Id`). I'm not at all a BNFC expert; I just read a bit of the manual.

Comment: @zeist: I copied the relevant macro expansion into the bottom of my answer. Hope it helps.